# GPRS connection watchdog

Tags: winapi, windows-mobile, gprs

I'd like to make my WM-based device reconnect to GPRS network, if connection has been broken.

There is a function in WinAPI

```
HRESULT WINAPI ConnMgrConnectionStatus(
  HANDLE  hConnection,
  DWORD   *pdwStatus
);
```

but it requires previous connection handle, and in my case it can be established manually.

Is there a way to get connection status without handles or subscribe to break event?

I can just check google.com, but that doesn't look good.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use the [`ConnMgrQueryDetailedStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416284.aspx) to get all the connections and run through them to check what you have?